# Difference between pointers to variables, and pointers to structures in C

Tags: c, pointers, structure

In learning C, I've just begun studying pointers to structures and have some questions.

Suppose I were to create a structure named `myStructure`, and then create a pointer `myStructurePointer`, pointing to `myStructure`.  Is `*myStructurePointer`, and `myStructure` two ways of referencing the same thing?  If so, why is it necessary to have the -> operator? It seems simpler to use `*myStructurePointer.variable_name` than `myStructurePointer->variable_name`.

Comment: To be more accurate, `myStructure` and `(*myStructurePointer)` are two ways of referencing the same thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right,

```
(*structurePointer).field
```

is exactly the same as

```
structurePointer->field
```

What you have, however, is :

```
*structurePointer.field
```

Which really tries to use the `.` operator on the pointer variable, then dereference the result of that - it won't even compile.  You need the parentheses as I have them in the first example above if you want the expressions to be equivalent.  The arrow saves at least a couple of keystrokes in this simple case.

The use of `->` might make more sense if you think about the case where the structure field has pointer type, maybe to another structure:

```
structurePointer->field->field2
```

vs.

```
(*(*structurePointer).field).field2
```

Comment: Yeah, it took me a while to figure that one out. Personally, I like the '->' syntax because it reminds me of Perl.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with `*myStructurePointer.variable_name` is that `*` binds less tight than `.`, so it would be interpreted as `*(myStructurePointer.variable_name)`. The equivalent of `myStructurePointer->variable_name` would be `(*myStructurePointer).variable_name`, where the parenthesis are required.

There is not difference between `a->b` and `(*a).b`, but `->` is easier to use, especially if there are nested structures. `(*(*(*a).b).c).d` is much less readable than ´a->b->c->d`.

Answer (score 4):

To generalize, learn your C operator precedence:

- [C Operator Precedence Table](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm)

Here the "." operator is processed before the "*" -> hence the need for parentheses

Comment: You can force the `*` to be processed before the `.` with liberal use of parenthesis, but the `->` notation was created as an easier-to-read alternative.

Comment: @Michael, I think what the OP is really asking is the difference between `(*p).f` and `p->f`.  The missing `()` are due to inexperience, I expect.

Comment: My answer made more sense when it was added below yours @Carl :-)

Comment: Sorry Carl.  It's hard to choose between multiple helpful answers.  I chose Mike's answer because it more thoroughly addressed my confusion; I am new to C, and understand precedence as much as it directly translates from Java, so the link provided by Michael was very helpful; however, you two seem to agree on who deserves credit, so I'm moving it.

Comment: No big deal, I thought I misunderstood the question, is all.

Answer (score 1):

#### Dennis Ritchie did note once that deref should probably have been a postfix operator<sup>1</sup>

Right, the following are equivalent:

```
pointer->field
(*pointer).field
pointer[0].field
```

If the indirection operator had postfix syntax C would have looked rather different but in that case it would not have needed `->` at all.

It's interesting to think about how the common C idioms would look in that alternate universe...

```
do s1++* = c = s2++*;
   while(c);

while(n-- > 0)
    s++* = '\0';

p*.x = 1;
p*.y = 2;
. . .
. . .
. . .
```

---

<sup>1. [**See The Development of the C Language.**](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html), Dennis M. Ritchie</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using the * dereferences the pointer, so you can use dot syntax to access the fields. If you don't dereference the pointer, then you use -> to access the fields. You can use whichever you prefer.

Answer (score -1):

I have been learning C recently, and i found this resource to be extremely helpful.

http://claymore.engineer.gvsu.edu/~steriana/226/C.CheatSheet.pdf